# Spark reader splits records when encounters control characters

Tags: regex, apache-spark, sed, non-printing-characters

I am trying to read file using spark reader. Spark reader splits the records in the file when it encounters the control characters like `^M`, `^H`, `^O`, `^P`.

To debug the issue I am trying to manually removing the control characters the file and testing record length with spark shell.

I tried to remove all control characters and check the record length:

```sh
sed -i 's/^[:print:]/ /g' <filename>
```

I found that it is also replacing punctuation characters like ? in space.
Please suggest the command that will helpful to replace all control characters into space.

Comment: Have you tried `tr '[:cntrl:]' ' ' <file`? `^[:print:]` matches one of `:`, `p`, `r`, `i`, `n`, and `t` at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` when used outside of a bracket expression mean *start of a string*. The `[:print:]` POSIX character class outside of a bracket expression does not match any printable chars, it matches a colon, `r`, `p`, `n`, `i`, `t` chars.

You can use

```sh
sed -i 's/[^[:print:]]/ /g' < filename>
```

It will replace every non-printable char with a literal space char.